# Custom seek bar with thumbs

Tags: android, user-interface, seekbar

I'm working on application where I have to implement a seekbar like this. I don't want to use external libraries. Is there any solution to implement this? Any help is appreciated.[image]

Comment: If you do not want to use external libraries then you need create one .

Comment: You should write an entirely new view from scratch, there is no way to use a customized Android SeekBar for your purpose, unfortunately...